# Is there a way to make an AWS S3 bucket without encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

AWS recently changed their policy. Amazon S3 now applies server-side encryption with Amazon S3 managed keys (SSE-S3) as the base level of encryption for every bucket in Amazon S3.

Is there a way to not make a S3 bucket encrypted by default or may be remove the added encryption?

Comment: Is there any strong reason why you want to remove default encryption?

Comment: There was a feature which required the encryption to be off, now that the policy has changed, i wanted to confirm if there was a way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It is not allowed to disable encryption.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/default-encryption-faq.html

This type of encryption is free and transparent, so there's no compelling reason to turn it off anyway.